# How to assign the ItemsSource of a DataGrid with code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datacontext, itemssource

I have a DataGrid in my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridBasket" Width="270" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadDataBindingBasket}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,10" />
```

I have some code to run a SQL query and assign the results to the grid:

```
DataSet dataSetBespokeBasket = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
adp.Fill(dataSetBespokeBasket, "LoadDataBindingBasket");
dataGridBasket.DataContext = dataSetBespokeBasket;
```

Question: Is there a way to leave out the ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadDataBindingBasket}" and just assign that in the C# code? It is a little clumsy to have to be bound to that name I assigned in the XAML, I'd like to be able to modify it at runtime for various use cases.

Comment: Yes there is.  Everything you do in XAML can be done in code-behind.    But there should be no need to do so.  Run your query in code-behind if you must.  But when you are done, all you need to to is assign the resulting collection to whatever property the DataGrid binds to with its ItemsSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the appropriate `DataTable` from `DataSet.Table` and assign it to `DataGrid.ItemsSource`:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
...

this.dataGridBasket.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables["MyDtabaseTablename"].DefaultView;
```